# problem with popup modal in javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html, popupwindow

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="keywords" content="mahasakthi harvester spares, combine harvester spares, kartar combine, agricultural harvester spares, standard combine harvester, claas combine harvester, claas dominator 400, kartar 3500g, standard tsc 513, combine harvester rubber track,  rubber track, baler spares, round baler, standard harvester spares, harvester spares parts, combine parts, harvester spare parts tamilnadu, claas harvester spares, harvester rubber track, kartar harvester spares"/>
        <title>Mahasakthi Harvester Spares</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/images/logo.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow" rel="stylesheet">
        <style>
             body{
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                background: url("assets/images/bg.jpg")no-repeat top;
                background-size: cover;
                background-attachment: fixed;
            }
            section
            {
                width: 87%;
                margin: 0 auto;
                padding: 1em;
                margin-top: 4em;
            }
            section h2{
                text-align: center;
                font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
                width: 17%;
                padding: 1%;
                color: #ffffff;
                background-color: #fc0321;
                margin: 0 auto;
                text-shadow:2px 2px 4px #000000;
            }
            section h3{
                text-align: center;
                font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
                width: 25%;
                padding: 1%;
                color: #ffffff;
                background-color: #fc0321;
                margin-bottom: 0.5em;
                text-shadow:2px 2px 4px #000000;
            }
            iframe{
                width:100%;
                padding: 1em 0;
            }
            form input,textarea{
                margin-bottom: 0.9em;
            }
            .form-container{
                width: 50%;
                float:left;
                padding: 1em;
                margin-bottom: 3em;
            }
            .address-container{
                width: 50%;
                float: right;
                margin-bottom: 3em;
            }
            .address-container p,.form-container p{
                text-align:justify;
            }
            input{
                padding: 0.1em;
            }

            input[type=submit]{
                padding: 1.5%;
                font-size: 24px;
                font-weight: 400;
                background-color: orangered;
                color: #fff;
                border: none;
                font-family:'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
            }
            input[type=submit]:hover{
                background-color: #fc0321;
                text-shadow:2px 2px 4px #000;
            }
            textarea{
                width: 99%;
            }
            #popup{
                   position: absolute;
                   top: 0;
                   bottom: 0;
                   left: 0;
                   right: 0;
                   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
                   display: block;
                   }
                   #popup div{
                       position: relative;
                       top: 50%;
                       left: 50%;
                       width: 40%;
                       padding: 6%;
                       transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
                       background-color: #fff;
                       text-align: center;
                   }
                   #popup div i{
                       font-size: 1.5em;
                       position: absolute;
                       right: 5px;
                       top: 5px;
                       cursor: pointer;
                   }
                   #popup div p{
                       font-size: 2em;
                   }
            @media only screen and (max-width:768px){
                section{
                    width: 100%;
                    margin-top: 2em;
                }
                .form-container{
                    width: 100%;
                    clear: left;
                }
                iframe{
                    width:100%;
                    margin: 0 auto;
                }
                .address-container{
                    float: left;

                }
                textarea{
                    width: 90%;
                }
                section h2{
                    width: 50%;
                }
                section h3{
                    width: 70%;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php require './header.html'; ?>
        <section>
            <h2>Contact Us</h2>
        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d1954.2639457126445!2d78.74887892394256!3d11.585663866213299!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0xd01afb36efb4c845!2sMahasakthi+Harvester+Spares!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1541082127241" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <div class="form-container">
            <h3>Enquire us</h3>
            <p><b>Our Product ranges from Machined spares, Fabricated spares, sheet metal spares, Rubber spares,Shafts,Bearings,Belts, Oils ,Grease,Filters,Rubber Tracks,Rollers,Sprockets to all miniature spares. We believe in building strong and lasting relationships with our customers based upon trust and mutual benefit. </b>
</p>
        <form method="post" action="">
            <input type="text"  name="name" required="requied" placeholder="Name *">            
            <input type="text" name="number"  required="required" placeholder="Contact No *">
            <input type="email" name="mail" required="required" placeholder="Email *">
            <textarea  placeholder="Requirement *" name="message" required="required"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>      
        </div>
        <div class="address-container">
            <h3>Our Shop</h3>
            <p><i class="fa fa-address-card" aria-hidden="true"></i> <b>6/380A,Cinthamani Complex,Near Honda Showroom,Mummudi,Thalaivasal,Attur TK,Salem DT,636112.</b></p>
                <p><i class="fa fa-mobile" aria-hidden="true"></i> <b>9443915660 | 9655565540</b></p>
                <p><i class="fa fa-mobile" aria-hidden="true"></i> <b>9655515540</b></p>
                <p><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> <b><a href="mailto:mahasakthi2018@gmail.com">mahasakthi2018@gmail.com</a></b></p>
                <h3>Mobile Shop</h3>
                <p><i class="fa fa-mobile" aria-hidden="true"></i> <b>9655151540</b></p>
                <h3>Shop Hours</h3>
                <p><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> <b>Monday to Saturday : 9 A.M to 8.30 P.M</b></p>
                <p><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> <b>Sunday : 9 A.M to 4 P.M</b></p>
        </div>
        </section> 
        <?php require './footer.html'; ?>     
        <?php 
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $num = $_POST['number'];
            $email = $_POST['mail'];
            $message = $_POST['message'];
             $email_to = "mahasakthi2018@gmail.com";
    $email_subject = "Enquiry from Website";
    $email_message = "Name: ".$name."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".$email."\n";
    $email_message .= "Contact No: ".$num."\n";
    $email_message .= "Requirement: ".$message."\n"; 
    $headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
    echo '<div id="popup"><div><i onclick="close()" class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i><p>Enquiry Received</p><p>We will get back to you shortly</p></div></div>';
        }
        ?>
        <script>
            function close(){
                document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "none";
            }
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to have the popup modal when the php mail process is sent.The popup window is displaying but it is not closing.I have the javascript function to close the popup modal but it is not working.Why it is not working properly?Can anyone help with this javascript problem?If I made any any mistake with the javascript,correct the mistake I did.

Comment: do you want to close modal on click of your icon or automatically?

Comment: If your question is not related to PHP, why does it have PHP code? The PHP is not helpful as it prevents us from fiddling with your code.

Comment: yes I want to close the modal on click of the icon